# Assign a paper to a reviewer based on keywords

Tags: java, algorithm, keyword

I was wondering if you know any algorithm that can do an automatic assignment for the following situation: I have some papers with a some keywords defined, and some reviewers that have some specific keywords defined. How could I do an automatic mapping, so that the reviewer could review the papers from his/her area of interest?

Comment: If you have them in a MySQL database, this can be done automatically with full-text search.

Comment: You're rarely going to get an exact match of a reviewer's keyword list and the paper's keyword list.  There will need to be some limitation on the number of papers assigned to a given reviewer!  So a constrained-similarity measure algorithm of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to using external tools [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) is a library that will allow you to search text based on (from their website)

- phrase queries, wildcard queries, proximity queries, range queries and more
- fielded searching (e.g., title, author, contents)
- date-range searching
- sorting by any field
- multiple-index searching with merged results
- allows simultaneous update and searching

Answer (score 0):

You will basically need to design your own parser, or specialize an existing parser according to your needs. You need to scan the papers, and according to your keywords,search and match your tokens accordingly. Then the sentences with these keywords are to be separated and displayed to the reviewer.

I would suggest the [Stanford NLP POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml). Every keyword that you would need, will fall under some part-of-speech. You can then just tag your complete document, and search for those tags and accordingly sort out the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) could be one solution.

It allows you to index documents either in a RAM directory, or within a real directory of your file system, and then to perform full-text searches.

Its proposes a lot of very interesting features like filters or analyzers. You can for example:

- remove the stop words depending on the language of the documents (e.g. for english: a, the, of, etc.);
- stem the tokens (e.g. function, functional, functionality, etc., are considered as a single instance);
- perform complex queries (e.g. review*, keyw?rds, "to be or not to be", etc.);
- and so on and so forth...

You should have a look! Don't hesitate to ask me some code samples if Lucene is the way you chose `:)`